# Where is the RingCentral ReadPresenceSettings set in the portal?

Tags: user-permissions, ringcentral

I see the `ReadPresenceSettings` permission in the API for my role, but I do not see it in the Online Account Portal (https://service.ringcentral.com). What does this correspond to in the portal so I can set/unset it?

### Permission in Role

#### Request

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/user-role/:roleId
GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/user-role/3
```

#### Response

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/user-role/3",
    "id": "3",
    "displayName": "Standard (International)",
    "description": "User level access with international dialing access.",
    "custom": false,
    "scope": "Self",
    "hidden": false,
    "siteCompatible": false,
    "permissions": [
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ReadPresenceSettings",
            "id": "ReadPresenceSettings",
            "assignable": false,
            "readOnly": false,
            "siteCompatible": "Independent"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

### Permission Info Exists

When I check the presence info endpoint, I see that it is called "Read Presence Settings" but there is no such permission in the portal.

#### Request

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/:permissionId
GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ReadPresenceSettings
```

#### Response

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ReadPresenceSettings",
    "id": "ReadPresenceSettings",
    "displayName": "Read Presence Settings",
    "assignable": false,
    "readOnly": false,
    "siteCompatible": "Independent",
    "category": {
        "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission-category/Features",
        "id": "Features"
    },
    "includedPermissions": []
}
```

I'm using the Postman with the collection here:

https://github.com/grokify/swaggman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RingCentral permissions can be fairly granular and not every API permission appears in the Online Account Portal.

Permissions that are assignable to users are indicated by the permission's boolean `assignable` property. This is set to `false` for `ReadPresenceSettings`.

Some permissions are child permissions of another permission that is assignable. In this case, they will be listed in a permissions `includedPermissions` property.

In this case, the assignable parent permission is: `ConfigurePresence` in the API or "Configure Presence" in the UI.

### Finding the Assignable Parent Permission

To find this using the API, call the permission list endpoint and then check each permission for `ReadPresenceSettings` in the `includedPermissions` property where the `assignable` property is also `true`.

#### Request

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission
```

#### Response

The response will include an array of permissions as follows. Filtering for permissions that are assignable and have `ReadPresenceSettings` permission as an included permissions returns only `ConfigurePresence` for me.

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission?page=1&perPage=100",
    "records": [
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ConfigurePresence",
            "id": "ConfigurePresence",
            "displayName": "Configure Presence",
            "description": "Allows to manage Presence settings",
            "assignable": true,
            "readOnly": false,
            "siteCompatible": "Independent",
            "category": {
                "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission-category/Features",
                "id": "Features"
            },
            "includedPermissions": [
                {
                    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/EditPresenceStatus",
                    "id": "EditPresenceStatus",
                    "assignable": false,
                    "readOnly": false,
                    "siteCompatible": "Independent"
                },
                {
                    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ReadPresenceSettings",
                    "id": "ReadPresenceSettings",
                    "assignable": false,
                    "readOnly": false,
                    "siteCompatible": "Independent"
                },
                {
                    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ReadPresenceStatus",
                    "id": "ReadPresenceStatus",
                    "assignable": false,
                    "readOnly": false,
                    "siteCompatible": "Independent"
                },
                {
                    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/EditPresenceSettings",
                    "id": "EditPresenceSettings",
                    "assignable": false,
                    "readOnly": false,
                    "siteCompatible": "Independent"
                }
            ]
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

### Updating the Permission

Once you have the assignable, parent permission, you can update it for the user as normal. Doing this will have child permissions enabled/disabled as well. For example, for `ReadPresenceSettings` you would update the user's role "Configure Presence" permission using the Online Account Portal as normal. If the user is using a built-in permission, you may need to create a new, modified role for the user if there isn't one already.

You can learn more about how to do this in this KB article:

https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Editing-the-Extension-Permissions-via-Web

Comment: Added the section "Updating the Permission" above to describe how to update an included permission.